# Javascript & the dom Form submission

Tags: javascript

The required task is when I run the task I get the messages I should in the console but from my automated educator an error, I have ran it through AI and they tell me I have the correct code, I am guessing it is something small I have missing, but I'd like to fix it and find out what I need to to learn from this.

Here is my task

1. Declare a variable form assign it the HTML element with the id of "contact-form"
2. Add a submit event handler to the form that calls a function named: handleSubmit
3. Create a function called handleSubmit, which takes a single parameter named: event
4. The handleSubmit function should:
   Prevent the default submit behavior.
   console.log("submitting form...")
   Retrieve the message entered into the element with id of "message"
   And assign it to the variable test
   console.log(test)
   submit the form
   console.log("form submitted")

I have come up with this code so far, I am stumped, could anyone help me understand where I am going wrong so I can learn from this? Thank you for your time.

```
    let test; // assignment to this variable is to be done inside the function you create
    // write your code below

    let form = document.getElementById("contact-form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

    function handleSubmit(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log("submitting form...");
       let test = document.getElementById("message").value;
       console.log(test);
       form.submit(); 
       console.log("form submitted");
    }
```

I have tried

```
event.target.submit();
event.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));
document.form.submit();
```

And some methods AI has given me, but they create more mistakes for the task needed. AI says my code is correct when checked next to the tasks given.

I get this error:

```
⚠ Hint
Does the function handleSubmit work? Does it prevent the default 
event? Does it read the value from the textarea element and assign 
it to a variable? Does it submit the form?
```

I'm given this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>

    <title>Form Submission</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="contact-form" method="POST"action="https://formdump.codeinstitute.net/">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" type="text"></textarea>
        <input id="submit-button" type="submit">
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-DrT5NfxfbHvMHux31Lkhxg42LY6of8TaYyK50jnxRnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Q: What exactly is the error message you're getting from the code you've shown?

Comment: Hi, sorry, Ive updated the above 

It says to me 

⚠ Hint
Does the function handleSubmit work? Does it prevent the default event? Does it read the value from the textarea element and assign it to a variable? Does it submit the form?

Comment: Why are you using `form.submit()`? Isn't your code [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/v7y4pc5d/)? If you're using an `<input>` or `<button>` with `type="submit"`, it does the exact same thing as `form.submit()`, so only choose one. You should probably also show your HTML code. Removing `<input type="submit" />` and just using `form.submit()` works correctly.

Comment: I am tasked with learning how to capture the submit event when a user submits a form, so you can handle the event in JavaScript, how to submit a form yourself, so you don't need to depend on a user to do it and how to prevent the default behaviour of the form, if you're going to override it with JavaScript... edit HTML added to OP

Comment: Removed the submit in the html and still the same outcome.... I'm pretty certain I shouldn't have to touch the html or it would be stated

Comment: @LightningMcQueen The instructions say "submit the form" after `console.log(test)`

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're doing everything the task says you should do. It's not clear what it thinks is wrong.

Comment: Im confused... is that not where I have it?  straight underneath console.log(test)

Comment: Thanks, maybe there is an error on the site I use.... I have enquired through their facilities , but no reply as of yet.

Thank you for your help on this matter!

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning to the global variable `test`. You've declared a local variable with the same name and you're assigning that instead.

Change

```
       let test = document.getElementById("message").value;
```

to

```
       test = document.getElementById("message").value;
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you! Such a small thing, shows I have to be extra careful! Thanks a million!